# New Page sending me to Archive page - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Adios Wordpress theme and I created a new category called Portfolio, however, it's taking me to the Archive page. I know this theme has a portfolio section but I can't seem to add multiple portfolios for my crew and share the same categories but show different content.

So decided to use another method but the damn archive page :(

So far, I've only installed SEO Ultimate and using the Meta Robot unticked the default - Author Archives etc. I also tried installed smart Archive Page Remove and unticked all the Archives except for Daily, Weekly, and Yearly Archives but that too doesn't work.

My page is https://preston-filmmaking.uk/portfolio/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you need to pay *very close attention* to slugs.  You cannot have two things (page, post, image, category, custom post type, etc).  Slug conflicts will cause all sorts of problems, like you are experiencing.

As long as you have a category with the slug `portfolio`, you can not have a page with the slug `portfolio` (nor a post with that slug, nor an image with that slug, nor a custom post type that uses that slug).

It *used to be* that you even needed to consider things that are in the trash - the slugs of items in the trash would conflict with published pages (but this was resolved in WP 4.5+)

There are programmatical workarounds, but my strong suggestion would be to simply change the slug for either the category or the page.

Comment: Hello,Thanks - I've tried to mess around with this slug and couldn't find a way to do this. My new page has the URL of 'https://preston-filmmaking.uk/portfolio'. My portfolio section does not have any URLs just categories. I can't find the Archive page so therefore do not know what to change.

Comment: You must change the slug of the _page_.  Edit the page.  Below the title is "permalink".  Click to edit it, and then save.